# textbox onchange call php function

Tags: php, forms, function, onchange

How can i call a PHP function from onchange on an HTML form textbox? I have tried

```
<input onchange="phpfunction()" ..... >

<?php
    function phpfunction() {
        my function
    }
?>
```

Any Help? I Can't seem to figure it out.

Thank You

Comment: No you can't, you must use javascript and call a php script with ajax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do an ajax call and post that your PHP.

Example:

**HTML:**

```
<input name="blah" onchange="mainInfo(this.value);">
```

**Javascript Function (AjaX)**

```
function mainInfo(id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "dummy.php",
        data: "mainid =" + id,
        success: function(result) {
            $("#somewhere").html(result);
        }
    });
};
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['mainid'])){
        mainInfo($_GET['mainid']);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't execute PHP in the browser.

Do an AJAX call or POST to a PHP function on the web server, or write a Javascript function that executes in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do it with JavaScript and send request to server. As HTML runs on client and php on sever.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery for this, cant use PHP on client.

```
<input onchange="callphpfunction()" ..... >
<script>
callphpfunction()   {
    $.post("file.php",function(data) {
        alert(data);
    });
}
</script>
```

**file.php**

```php
<?php
function phpfunction() {
    echo $data;
}
phpfunction();
```